# Can JSONP interfere with getting background images?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using JSONP to return a status, but I also show a pic and some details as an item in a list. When I load the page, I'm seeing a delay in loading all the pics except the first one which is taking about as long as the JSONP calls to pull the status. You can see that [here](http://screencast.com/t/8hbejuvMkkCm).

Is there something inherent with JSONP that would affect the loading of my background images?  I consider that an async call so I'm not sure why the browser would block the calls to pull the image. Here's the CSS I'm using (ID is dynamically generated and supplied at runtime as I iterate through the items in the list):

```
<div class='avatar status available' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/pics/{id}.jpg);'><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was not to use CSS but instead the `<img>` tag.  So now my code turns into:

```
<div class='avatar status available'><img onerror='imgError(this)' src='https://services.xxx.com/pics/{id}.jpg'/></div>
```

This results in the images being loaded as expected without being blocked and I get the benefit of checking for errors if the image is bad to send a default image:

```
function imgError (image) {
    image.onerror = function () {
        this.parent().addClass('user');
    }
    image.src = "/resources/img/user.png";
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For show images in background rule, you need the absolute route (URL) of image or resource. In your link the absolute (URL) is [`http://content.../d812611d-5284-4abe-bb85-4ccda1424f16/2013-04-18_1722.png`](http://content.screencast.com/users/lsacco/folders/Jing/media/d812611d-5284-4abe-bb85-4ccda1424f16/2013-04-18_1722.png)

Show dynamic images from CSS is don't recommended.